# What is the best way to handle a lot of images from a shared hosting plan?

Tags: performance, http, browser, hosting

I have a shared hosting plan and am designing a single page site which will include a slideshow. The browser typically limits the number of simultaneous requests to a single domain. I don't expect a lot of traffic, but I would like the traffic I do receive to have fast load times. I may be able to add unlimited subdomains, but does that really affect the speed for the customer considering they are probably the only one polling my server and all subdomains point to the same processor? I have already created two versions of every image, one for the slideshow, and one for larger format via AJAX request, but the lag times are still a little long for my taste. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you contrive a bunch of subdomains to maximize parallel connections, you should profile your page load behavior so you know where most of the time is being spent. There might be easier and more rewarding optimizations to make first.

There are several tools that can help with this, use all of them:

- https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/
- http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/
- http://www.webpagetest.org/

Some important factors to look at are cache optimization and image compression.

If you've done all those things, and you are sure that you want to use multiple (sub)domains, then I would recommend using a content delivery network (CDN) instead of hosting the static files (images) on the same shared server. You might consider [Amazon's CloudFront service](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/). It's super easy to set up, and reasonably priced.

Lastly, don't get carried away with too many (sub)domains, because each host name will require a separate DNS lookup; find a balance.

Comment: I have awarded you the bounty. Your answer, while the only one submitted, is rather complete, and for that I thank you. I did have one part of my question that I may not have asked well. Is my intuition correct that multiple subdomains on a shared plan will not increase speed appreciably, as they are all querying the same server/processor, and image serving times by the server outweigh typical latency times for a request? That said, I think that your CDN comment is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: It depends on the hardware and software, but modern servers are capable of handling multiple requests in parallel. So it isn't necessarily true that you would have a one-request-at-a-time bottleneck. A common configuration, for example, is Apache HTTPD running in prefork mode, which allocates a different process for each request. Each process can run in parallel if there are multiple cores. But of course there may be bottlenecks like disk I/O. Really, every scenario is different, but it's actually possible to get remarkable throughput from a single server. Regardless, a CDN is a good idea.

Comment: Regarding your question about serving multiple images from a single page. A critical bottleneck is probably the connections-per-host limit of the browser. So you actually might see a significant improvement by using multiple subdomains, even if the subdomains are served from the same server. This is easier to visualize by looking at resource loading waterfall diagrams like those generated by the tools I linked to.